# Bluetooth Can't be found by any bluetooth devise and vice versa on ubuntu 18.02

Tags: bluetooth

When I run this Command: `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`, I get this result:

```
[    1.191428] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    2.305017] battery: [Firmware Bug]: battery: (dis)charge rate invalid.
[   33.326025] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   33.326063] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   33.326067] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   33.326070] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   33.326073] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   33.706669] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   33.707664] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   33.723673] Bluetooth: hci0: mediateur-HP-250-G4-Notebook-PC
[   33.724668] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   34.463237] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd failed with error -2
[   34.463242] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd not found
[   35.722662] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   35.722664] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   35.722669] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   36.489036] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   36.489696] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  157.688134] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  157.688142] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  157.688152] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  198.002092] audit: type=1107 audit(1632820689.262:84): pid=952 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2189 label="snap.skype.skype" peer_pid=1044 peer_label="unconfined"
[  934.928635] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  934.929223] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

Comment: Please check your release; you may not be using Ubuntu, as there was no release in 2018-February (ie. 18.02)

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to get the proper firmware for the Bluetooth device for it to work properly. Fortunately, it’s not too difficult.

Here’s what you need to do:

1. Download [this Broadcom firmware from GitHub](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd)
2. Open Terminal and copy the file to the appropriate location:

   ```
   sudo cp ~/Downloads/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to change the source location if you did not download the file to your Downloads directory.</sup>
3. Shut the computer down
4. Restart the computer

This should give you a working Bluetooth device.